# Using filedialog.askdirectory() with tkinter and pyglet freezes the application

Tags: python, tkinter, pyglet, filedialog

I've been trying to create my own GUI mp3 player with pyglet module
 and i'm running into an error when clicking the 'd' button (dir_btn) as the entire GUI application freezes and furthermore, 
the IDE (pycharm) does not show any error

here's the specific function:

```
def add_songs(n=0):
if n == 0:
    dir_name=filedialog.askdirectory() #here is where the error occurs
else:
    dir_name=''

print("out")
song_list.delete(0, END)

temp=create_songs_list(dir_name)
if len(temp)==0:
    song_list.insert(END,"No Songs found...")
else:
    for i in temp:
        song_list.insert(END, i[len(dir_name) :])
    scroll.config(command=song_list.yview)
```

here is the entire code:

```
from pyglet import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
def control_song(event):
    global play_btn
    if player.source==None:
        song_list.unbind('<Double-1>')
        song_list.bind('<space>',control_song)
        src = media.load(song_list.get(ACTIVE))
        player.queue(src)
        player.volume = 0.3

    if play_btn['text']==' ▶ ':
        player.play()
        play_btn.configure(text='||')
    else:
        player.pause()
        play_btn.configure(text=' ▶ ')

def add_frames():
    global lower_frame
    global upper_frame
    global left_frame

    lower_frame = Frame(window, background="blue")
    upper_frame = Frame(window, background="green")
    left_frame = Frame(window, background="red")

    upper_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
    lower_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
    left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", rowspan=2)

    window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
    window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
    window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
    window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    lower_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=5) # back button frame
    lower_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1) # play button frame
    lower_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=5) # forward button frame

    lower_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # all 3 control buttons frame

    upper_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    upper_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

def mod_options():
    global options_open
    if window.columnconfigure(0)['weight']== 0:
        window.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    else:
        window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)

def add_widgets():
    global play_btn
    global back_btn
    global forward_btn
    global triple_btn
    global dir_btn
    global scroll
    global song_list

    scroll=Scrollbar(upper_frame)          #song list scroll bar
    scroll.grid(column=1,sticky='nse')

    song_list = Listbox(upper_frame,yscrollcommand=scroll.set)#song list box
    song_list.grid(row=0,sticky='nswe')
    song_list.bind('<Double-1>',control_song)

    back_btn = Button(lower_frame, text="◀◀")# back button
    back_btn.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='e') #

    play_btn = Button(lower_frame, text=" ▶ ",command=control_song)#play button
    play_btn.grid(column=1,row=0)             #

    forward_btn_btn = Button(lower_frame, text="▶▶")#forward button
    forward_btn_btn.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky='w') #

    triple_btn=Button(left_frame,text='≡',command=mod_options)#options button
    triple_btn.grid()                                         #

    dir_btn=Button(left_frame,text='d',command=add_songs)#options button
    dir_btn.grid()                                         #

def create_songs_list(dir_name=''):
    s_list=list()

    extensions = ["mp3"]
    s_list.clear()
    if dir_name=='':
        lst = os.listdir()
    else:
        lst = os.listdir(dir_name)

    for i in lst:
        i_list = str(i).split(".")
        if i_list[len(i_list) - 1].lower() in extensions:
            s_list.append((dir_name+"/" if dir_name!='' else '')+i)
    return s_list

def add_songs(n=0):
    if n == 0:
        dir_name=filedialog.askdirectory()
    else:
        dir_name=''

    print("out")
    song_list.delete(0, END)

    temp=create_songs_list(dir_name)
    if len(temp)==0:
        song_list.insert(END,"No Songs found...")
    else:
        for i in temp:
            song_list.insert(END, i[len(dir_name) :])
        scroll.config(command=song_list.yview)

player = media.Player()
window = Tk()

window.title("mp3 player")
window.geometry("500x300")

add_frames()
add_widgets()

add_songs(1)

window.mainloop()
```

My best approach was using multiprocessing but it seems like a lot of work for just getting a directory

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately tkinter has a lot of blocking commands, you will have to use a combination of threads for it. I made an example for Pyglet a while ago, which should be added shortly.

Here is a working example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as _ProcessPoolExecutor

from pyglet.event import EventDispatcher as _EventDispatcher

import os


class _Dialog(_EventDispatcher):
    executor = _ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

    @staticmethod
    def _open_dialog():
        raise NotImplementedError

    def open(self):
        future = self.executor.submit(self._open_dialog, self._dialog)
        future.add_done_callback(self._dispatch_event)

    def _dispatch_event(self, future):
        raise NotImplementedError


class FileOpenDialog(_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, title="Open File", initial_dir=os.path.curdir, filetypes="", multiple=False):
        from tkinter import filedialog
        
        self._dialog = filedialog.Open(title=title,
            initialdir=initial_dir,
            filetypes=filetypes,
            multiple=multiple
        )

    @staticmethod
    def _open_dialog(dialog):
        import tkinter as tk
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        return dialog.show()

    def _dispatch_event(self, future):
        self.dispatch_event('on_dialog_open', future.result())

    def on_dialog_open(self, filename):
        """Event for filename choice"""
        pass



class FileSaveDialog(_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, title="Save As", initial_dir=os.path.curdir, initial_file="", filetypes="", default_ext=""):
        from tkinter import filedialog
        self._dialog = filedialog.SaveAs(title=title,
            initialdir=initial_dir,
            initialfile=initial_file,
            filetypes=filetypes,
            defaultextension=default_ext,
        )
        
    @staticmethod
    def _open_dialog(dialog):
        import tkinter as tk
        from tkinter import filedialog
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        return dialog.show()

    def _dispatch_event(self, future):
        self.dispatch_event('on_dialog_save', future.result())

    def on_dialog_save(self, filename):
        """Event for filename choice"""
        pass



FileOpenDialog.register_event_type('on_dialog_open')
FileSaveDialog.register_event_type('on_dialog_save')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #save_as = FileSaveDialog(initial_file="test", filetypes=[("PNG", ".png"),("24-bit Bitmap", ".bmp")])
    #save_as.open()
    

    #@save_as.event
    #def on_dialog_save(filename):
    #    print("FILENAMES ON SAVE!", filename)
    
    open_dialog = FileOpenDialog(filetypes=[("PNG", ".png"),("24-bit Bitmap", ".bmp")], multiple=True)
    open_dialog.open()
    
    @open_dialog.event
    def on_dialog_open(filename):
        print("FILENAMES ON OPEN!", filename)
```

Comment: as a newbie I'm having a bit difficulty understand what you've done
could you explain in algorithmic terms what you've done?
and what are the prerequisites i need to know to better understand?

Comment: What this does is wrap the tk blocking function in a thread, runs it, then return it's results into a function. That function dispatches an event through pyglet to any listening functions; in this case `on_dialog_open`.