# Calling filedialog from inside a class Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, openfiledialog

I am trying to write an app in tkinter python that allows you to browse and choose a folder. I am using a class for each frame in my app, for example: `BrowseFolders` frame. In one of my frames I have a button that calls a command that opens `filedialog.askdirectory`. However, everytime I push the button the app seems to freeze and I have no other option other than closing it.

This is my class (notice the `self.selectFolder_button`):

```
class BrowseFolders(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container, bg='#232228')
        self.path = ''

        # big title
        pyglet.font.add_file('ARCENA.ttf')
        self.Mp3Scanner_label = tk.Label(self, text="MP3 Scanner", font=('AR CENA', 70),
                                         background='#232228', foreground='#E3EEF9')
        self.slogan_label = tk.Label(self, text='Upload your files to MongoDB', font=('AR CENA', 30),
                                     background='#232228', foreground='#E3EEF9')
        self.selectFolder_button = tk.Button(self, text="Select Folder", font=('AR CENA', 15),
                                             background='grey', command=self.select_folder)

        self.pack()

    def select_folder(self):
        self.path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='/', title="Select Folder")

    def pack(self):
        self.Mp3Scanner_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.35, anchor='center')
        self.slogan_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor='center')
        self.selectFolder_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.85, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.08, anchor='center')
        super().pack(expand=True, fill='both')


 class App(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.title('MP3 Scanner')
         self.geometry('600x450')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    BrowseFolders(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

I've already tried using `lambda`, changing my `select_folder()` method to be static, writing the method outside my class. Anything I do where the button somehow calls this function freezes my app. The only case where this does work is when my frame isn't a class.

Comment: what do you mean it freezes? it just requires the user to select a file and doesn't allow to focus on the main window until a selection is made or the filedialog is closed

Comment: I'm not seeing the same behaviour. The `askdirectory` call works as I'd expect it to. How are you running your code? Are you using some kind of IDE? Some of them have tkinter trouble.

Comment: Im using pycharm, just tried running it from the cmd, wont work either.

Comment: it freezes - the project stops responding and also doesn't open the filedialog window.

Comment: are you running the exact code you have provided here? we can't reproduce the problem, you should provide a [mre] (the current size is great but it doesn't reproduce the problem)

Comment: I am running the exact same code, nothing further. the only things missing are the imports:

Comment: import tkinter as tk
import pyglet
from tkinter import filedialog

Comment: code works correctly on `Linux Mint 20`, `Python 3.8`. Maybe problem is only on systems which you use. OR problem makes Python version which you use. You could add all details in question (not in comment).

Comment: There is similar issue: [using-filedialog-askdirectory-with-tkinter-and-pyglet-freezes-the-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716631/using-filedialog-askdirectory-with-tkinter-and-pyglet-freezes-the-application).  Removing `pyglet.font.add_file('ARCENA.ttf')` fixes the issue.

Comment: If you are in Windows, try the [`loadfont()`](https://github.com/ifwe/digsby/blob/f5fe00244744aa131e07f09348d10563f3d8fa99/digsby/src/gui/native/win/winfonts.py#L15) instead of using `pyglet`.

Comment: @acw1668 I attempted to make this function work but no matter what i pass into the function, it fails while decoding. I have tried passing in `file path`, `file.read()` content, `file.read().encode()` content, `file.read().encode()` extended into a bytearray but none of them work. 

what exactly do i have to pass in the function arg? I have the ttf file on disk obviously.

just trying to find an alternate of pyglet add font as that one has some issues with threading model.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much!
The problem really was the font, I removed `pyglet.font.add_file('ARCENA.ttf')` and now its working!